# Как писать юнит-тесты под Android в Eclipse

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня есть приложение, в нем класс Authorization, в классе есть метод:

```
private void login() {
    if (!RCP.NOT_LOGIN)
        return;
    String info = null;
    int worning = 0;
    String login = textLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    String passHash = hash(
            hash(textPass.getText().toString(), "SHA-1"), "MD5");
    info = DbWorker.setUser(login);

    // проверка успешности создания пользователя
    if (info == null)
        info = DbWorker.checkPass(passHash);
    else
        worning = R.string.aut_wrong_user_name;

    // проверка корректности ввода пароля
    if (info == null)
        info = DbWorker.checkActive();
    else if (worning == 0)
        worning = R.string.aut_wrong_user_pass;
    // проверка легитимности пользователя
    if (info == null)
        info = DbWorker.logIn();
    else if (worning == 0)
        worning = R.string.aut_wrong_user_activate;
    // проверка валидности пользователя
    if (info == null)
        info = DbWorker.setFIO();
    else if (worning == 0)
        worning = R.string.aut_wrong_permission;

    // проверка наличия прав доступа
    if (info == null)
        if (port.isChecked()) {
            inten2();
        } else {
            inten();}
    else if (worning == 0)
        worning = R.string.autho_error_reg_not_found;

    if (worning != 0)
        errorMes(worning).show();
    // запись в журнале, при неудачной регистрации
    if (RCP.NOT_LOGIN)
        DbLog.writeEvent(DbLog.EV_USER_LOGIN_FAILURE, 3, info, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Хочу сделать юнит тесты, что бы каждый раз после очередных "переделок" в ручную не тестить эту часть. Юнит-тесты, никогда не писал, но видимо настал тот час.

Может кто-то из вас уже был в подобной ситуации и посоветует с чего начать?

P.s. читал гул документацию, и сейчас читаю "Android Application Testing 
Guide" от Diego Torres Milano. Но я бы хотел найти пример "на пальцах", в IDE ECLIPSE. Может кому не жалко времени, запостит простенький пример, по приведенному коду(на легитимность введенных данных в поля логина и пароля))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После длительного поиска пришел в выводу, о неизбежности использования AndroidStudio в качестве IDE. 
Внятного, простого в освоении юнит-тестирования в реалиях Eclipce, я так и не нашел (под Андройд).

Сам гугл считает основным средством для тестирования Ecspresso, в документации достаточно просто и подробно все описано. Сам Ecspresso, можно использовать после импорта проекта в AndroidStudio, в принципе проблем не возникло.

Но есть нюанс, если обновить Android SDK Build-Tools до версий выше 24.0.1 может не работать ADB под ОС Windows XP. Пришлось поставить более старую версию и игнорировать обновления(.

Процесс создания и запуска тестов описан в официальной документации очень подробно, так что дерзайте.
Вот небольшая [статья](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/an-introduction-to-espresso/)([на русском](http://java-help.ru/introduction-to-android-espresso/)), для понимания основных принципов.

Comment: Андройд Студия так же работает под Linux (например, Ubuntu). Не желаете попробовать? Это не сложно. Просто, чтобы не сталкиваться с ограничениями из-за ОС.

Comment: @DimXenon. Да вы правы, но в контексте моего проекта есть дескопная часть под Windows, a т.к. пользователи - госслужищие в подовляющем большинстве они пользуют Windows XP. Именно этим продиктована моя привязка к ОС.

Comment: Ок. С госслужбами знаком. Понимаю. Вопросов больше не имею.